# How to register an object in jersey 2(ResourceConfig)

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jersey-2.0, jdbi

I want to register a class component(Object) in jersey not class reference. 
I create a `XYZResource` class that be called by `main()` method and it be configured through jersey with `DBI` object. `DAOService daoService` has connection DBI connection and the getDetails() that execute query and return result.

I use IntelliJ IDE and run through Main Class `com.example.Main`

when i hit my url `http://localhost:9000/resource/test` than it through error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in com.example.AdminResource class.

    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:392)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:535)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:483)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:420)
root cause

A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in com.example.AdminResource class.

    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Collector.throwIfErrors(Collector.java:88)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justCreate(Utilities.java:852)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:814)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:906)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:898)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:174)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:103)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:128)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:110)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:65)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:250)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1010)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:535)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:483)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:420)
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in com.example.AdminResource class.
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getConstructor(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:189)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getConstructor(Utilities.java:159)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justCreate(Utilities.java:850)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:814)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:906)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:898)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:174)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:103)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:128)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:110)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:65)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:250)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1010)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:535)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:483)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:420)
```

Technology Use:

- Java - 8
- Embedded tomcat - 8
- Jersey 2.5.1 (REST)
- JDBI 2.63.1 (DB Service)

---

Main.java

```
package com.example;

import com.core.db.DAOService;
import com.example.servlets.HelloWorldServlet;
import com.example.util.abc;
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
import org.skife.jdbi.v2.DBI;

public class Main {

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.setPort(9000);

    String baseDoc = new File("src/main/webapp").getAbsolutePath();
    Context ctx = tomcat.addContext("/servletSample", baseDoc);

    tomcat.addWebapp(null, "", baseDoc);
    tomcat.addServlet(ctx, "HelloWorld", new HelloWorldServlet());
    ctx.addServletMapping("/*", "HelloWorld");

    try { 

        final DBI XYZDBI = new DBI(/*url*/, /*username*/, /*password*/);
        /* DAOService is a class that has function getDetails() that retrive   data from database */
        final DAOService daoService = XYZDBI.onDemand(DAOService.class);
        final org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig jerseyResource = new org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig();

        /* Register XYZResource class instance with jersey Resouce */
        jerseyResource.register(new XYZResource(daoService));

        tomcat.start();
        } catch (LifecycleException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>my-jersey</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<build>
    <finalName>my-embed-tomcat</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
   <!-- Dependencies for Jersey Web Application -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.42</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-mvc-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

   <!-- Dependencies for Embedded Tomcat -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
       <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
       <version>8.0.26</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
       <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
       <version>8.0.26</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
       <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
       <version>8.0.26</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <!--org.skife.jdbi.v2-->
       <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
       <artifactId>jdbi</artifactId>
       <version>2.63.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.7</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
       <version>2.8.0.rc2</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
       <version>2.8.3</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.8.0.rc2</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
       <version>2.8.0.rc2</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>microsoft.com</groupId>
       <artifactId>sqlJdbc4</artifactId>
       <version>4.0.2206.100</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
       <version>2.6</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

---

XYZResource.java

```
package com.example;

import com.core.db.DAOService;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.google.common.base.Optional;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.*;

@Path("resource")
public class XYZResource {

    private final DAOService daoService;

    public XYZResource(DAOService daoService) {
        this.daoService = daoService;        
    }

    @GET
    public String helloworld() {
        return "User - Resource";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    public Response test() {
        Set<String> User = daoService.getDetails();
        Iterator<String> itr = User.iterator();
        return Response.status(200).entity(itr.next().toString())
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET")
                .build();
        }
    }
}
```

---

MyApplication.java

```
package com.example;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature;

public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {

        this.packages(MyApplication.class.getPackage().getName()).register(JspMvcFeature.class);
    }
}
```

---

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Jersey Jersey Application</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>Jersey Application Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.MyApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <!-- pass to next filter if Jersey/App returns 404 -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.forwardOn404</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Jersey Application Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Update**

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <build>
        <finalName>my-embed-tomcat</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <tomcat.version>8.0.28</tomcat.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


   <dependencies>
s
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
           <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
           <version>2.25.1</version>
       </dependency>

       <!-- Dependencies for Jersey Web Application -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-mvc-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
           <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
           <version>2.5.1</version>
       </dependency>
       <!-- Dependencies for Embedded Tomcat -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
           <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
           <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
           <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
           <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
           <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
           <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <!--org.skife.jdbi.v2-->
           <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
           <artifactId>jdbi</artifactId>
           <version>2.63.1</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
           <version>1.7.7</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
           <version>2.8.0.rc2</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
           <version>2.8.3</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
           <version>2.8.0.rc2</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
           <version>2.8.0.rc2</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>microsoft.com</groupId>
           <artifactId>sqlJdbc4</artifactId>
           <version>4.0.2206.100</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
           <version>2.6</version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

---

Main.java

```
package com.example;

import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.FilterDef;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.FilterMap;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletProperties;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import java.io.File;

/**
 * @author Paul Samsotha.
 */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setPort(9000);

        File base = new File(".");
        Context context = tomcat.addContext("", base.getAbsolutePath());

        Tomcat.addServlet(context, "default", new DefaultServlet());
        context.addServletMapping("/*", "default");

        final FilterDef def = new FilterDef();
        final FilterMap map = new FilterMap();

        def.setFilterName("jerseyFilter");
        def.setFilter(getJerseyFilter());
        context.addFilterDef(def);

        map.setFilterName("jerseyFilter");
        map.addURLPattern("/api/*");
        context.addFilterMap(map);

        tomcat.start();

        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static Filter getJerseyFilter() {
        final ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig()
                .register(new HelloResource(new Service()))
                .register(JspMvcFeature.class)
                .property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true);
        return new ServletContainer(config);
    }

    public static class Service {
        public String getMessage() {
            return "Hello Tomcat!";
        }
    }

    @Path("tomcat")
    public static class HelloResource {
        private final Service service;

        public HelloResource (Service service) {
            this.service = service;
        }

        @GET
        public String get() {
            return this.service.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a lot of unnecessary stuff going on. You have two different configurations. Pick one. The problem is caused by the package scanning, which is picking up the resource and trying to register it.

Just get rid of the web.xml and `MyApplication` and just use the `ResourceConfig` you're currently using in the main class. Then you can register the servlet programmatically using Jersey's [`ServletContainer`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.21/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer.html) which is both a `Filter` *and* a `HttpServlet`. So you don't need the web.xml to configure Jersey as  `Filter`. The `ServletContainer` is already a `Filter`

```
new SevletContainer(youResourceConfig);
```

I'm not too familiar with Tomcat embedded so I can't say how to register filters, but I'm sure a quick search will find you the answer. Just register the `ServletContainer` as a filter.

The `jersey.config.servlet.filter.forwardOn404` init-param can also be configured with the filter registration. Or you can just configure it with the `ResourceConfig`, with its `property` method

```
resourceConfig.property("jersey.config.servlet.filter.forwardOn404", true);
```

Or better yet, use [the constant](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.21/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletProperties.html#FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404)

```
property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true);
```

### UPDATE

Here is a complete setup (based on your example) that works.

```
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.FilterDef;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.FilterMap;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletProperties;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import java.io.File;

/**
 * @author Paul Samsotha.
 */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setPort(9000);

        File base = new File(".");
        Context context = tomcat.addContext("", base.getAbsolutePath());

        Tomcat.addServlet(context, "default", new DefaultServlet());
        context.addServletMapping("/*", "default");

        final FilterDef def = new FilterDef();
        final FilterMap map = new FilterMap();

        def.setFilterName("jerseyFilter");
        def.setFilter(getJerseyFilter());
        context.addFilterDef(def);

        map.setFilterName("jerseyFilter");
        map.addURLPattern("/api/*");
        context.addFilterMap(map);

        tomcat.start();

        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static Filter getJerseyFilter() {
        final ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig()
                .register(new HelloResource(new Service()))
                .register(JspMvcFeature.class)
                .property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true);
        return new ServletContainer(config);
    }

    public static class Service {
        public String getMessage() {
            return "Hello Tomcat!";
        }
    }

    @Path("tomcat")
    public static class HelloResource {
        private final Service service;

        public HelloResource (Service service) {
            this.service = service;
        }

        @GET
        public String get() {
            return this.service.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

A few changes I made:

1. Not sure why you are using Tomcat 7 Servlet API. I Changed that to the 8.x version of your other Tomcat dependencies.
2. I also excluded the Servlet API from the Jersey MVC dependency, as that pulls in an older 2.4 Servlet API

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-mvc-jsp</artifactId>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
               <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. I added a `DefaultServlet` to handle the pages. From testing (again I am not Tomcat expert), it seems [this is required](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/How-to-properly-map-a-filter-in-tomcat-embedded-td5054372.html)

With the example you should be able to GET

```
http://localhost:9000/api/tomcat
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am new in java. I am trying according to your suggestion, but still it not working.

Comment: I create a repository.  please check the code https://github.com/eigenharsha/jersey-app.git

Comment: thanks for your update, it seems to very similar to my requirement. I used your updated example. when I run this then it prompts an error 
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jersey/repackaged/com/google/common/base/Predicate
 at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)`

I search for this error and found a dependency requirement like 
`<dependency>
           <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
           <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
           <version>2.25.1</version>
       </dependency>`
again I face new error.

Comment: You need to use the same Jersey version for your Jersey dependencies. In your post the Jersey MVC is 2.5.1. This conflicts with the version in your above comment. You are better off using the newer versions.

Comment: yes, I resolve this error. I updated my code.
but when i hit `localhost:9000/api/tomcat` then it gives 404

Comment: Did you also use `map.addURLPattern("/api/*");`? and have the endpoint `@Path("tomcat")` like in my example?

Comment: I don't see any change at all from your updated code and the code in my post. I tested my code, and it worked fine. And you still haven't updated the Jersey versions, though I don't think that would cause the 404

Comment: https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/71f1169a4c239d91133eafa184fa229f. disregard the Jackson stuff (for JSON) and the test-framework and jetty plugin. I was using an old project when testing.

Comment: Also using the `dependencyManagement` allows you to avoid using `<version>` for all the dependencies. It makes sure that you are using compatible versions of Jersey dependencies

Answer (score 1):

First, Thanks to [peeskillet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2587435/peeskillet) who solved my problem. I search on the net but I did not find the exact solution.

For better reference and understandability, I create a demo application on git-hub.

> [jersey-mvc-jsp-freemarker-with-embedded-tomcat](https://github.com/eigenharsha/jersey-mvc-jsp-freemarker-with-embedded-tomcat)

Application Used

- Tomcat v8.x
- Jersey v2.5.1
- JSP
- YML
- Freemarker
- HTML/Angular/JavaScript

> ```
> final ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig()
>     .packages(Main.class.getPackage().getName())
>     .register(new Resource(new Core(), configuration)) // create instance of Resource and dynamically register
>     .register(JspMvcFeature.class) // register jspMVC
>     .register(FreemarkerMvcFeature.class) // register FreemarkerMVC
>     .property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true);
>
> return new ServletContainer(config);
> ```